# CSS - Cross Browser Navigation Div Size

Tags: html, css

I have a `CSS` glitch in my currently under developed project. I am not sure how to fix it When I view the page in Firefox it works fine, but when I open it in chrome, the menu div fill half of the page increasing it's size . My Landing Page is at [Here](http://freematrimonial.base.pk). You can easily find link to my [CSS](http://freematrimonial.base.pk/css/style.css) by viewing the page source. Can anyone tell me what I lack in `CSS`. Thanks

Comment: Could you please make a JSFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/) of the menu itself with the respective css and javascript?

Comment: try remove `min-height: 100%` in `.navbar` in style.css line 177

Comment: Brilliant  @TamilSelvan, It worked, I have updated the CSS, now working fine on both browsers. You can put it in answer, I will accept it

Comment: @AndrewAdam. Thanks for your time. problem solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try remove `min-height: 100%` in `.navbar` in style.css line 177 . This should fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

you're usign the class **.navbar** on two elements which glitches on chrome cause of the min-height property, by removing class **.navbar** from **.nav_bottom** should fix problem

Comment: I removed the min height property and it worked and yes you are right, this is the glitch. Thanks